# Put PNG Image on Image taken

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have an activity with an ImageView where it holds the photo that taken from the camera. Now I want to add a PNG image (when the ImageButton clicked) above the photo that is already in the ImageView. Is that possible? And if yes then how? 
Here is the Activity with the ImageView.

```
public class PicturePreview extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_picture_preview);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String path = bundle.getString("ImagePath");
    Log.e("Path of Image is", path);


    File imgFile = new File(path);
    if (imgFile.exists()) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photopreview);
        image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);


        ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.img1);
        effect1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Either going to have to do a custom ImageView or use a RelativeLayout with one ImageView on top of the other.

Comment: I will try the second.. Also I dont know what is the custom ImageView but I will search to find.. Thank you.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another imageview over the photopreview imageview in your activity_picture_preview xml and set visibility as gone

Once the imagebutton clicked set the png image for that imageview and make that imageview visible by setvisiblity as visible

On Your Xml

```
<RelativeLayout>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/photopreview .../>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/pngpreview 
  visibilty="gone" .../>

</RelativeLayout>
```

On Your activity

```
ImageView pngimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pngpreview );

ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.img1);
        imgbtn .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
          //you already have bitmap
           pngimage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
          pngimage.setVisibity(View.Visible);
            }
        });
```